# Parser for file made up of sections

Tags: ruby, complexity, cyclomatic-complexity

I'm parsing a file made up of various sections. I have a `current_section` variable that tracks which portion of the file I'm currently processing and the following `check_for_next_section` method that returns either the next section based on the contents of the current line or `current_section` if there are no matches based on the contents of the current line.

This method is getting flagged by rubocop for both 'perceived complexity' and 'cyclomatic complexity'. How can I reduce these?

```
SECTION_HEADERS = {                                                                                             
  hawaii_1: '"[2] For Hawaii, the following Postal Codes are Zone 44 for Ground',                               
  hawaii_2: '"For Hawaii, the following Postal Codes are Zone 46 for Ground',                                   
  alaska_1: '"[3] For Alaska, the following Postal Codes are Zone 44 for Ground',                               
  alaska_2: '"For Alaska, the following Postal Codes are Zone 46 for Ground'                                    
}.freeze                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                
def check_for_next_section(line, current_section)                                                               
  return :zones if current_section == :preamble && line.starts_with?('Dest. ZIP')                               
  return :hawaii_1 if current_section == :zones && !line.blank? && line.starts_with?(SECTION_HEADERS[:hawaii_1])
  return :hawaii_2 if current_section == :hawaii_1 && line.starts_with?(SECTION_HEADERS[:hawaii_2])             
  return :alaska_1 if current_section == :hawaii_2 && line.starts_with?(SECTION_HEADERS[:alaska_1])             
  return :alaska_2 if current_section == :alaska_1 && line.starts_with?(SECTION_HEADERS[:alaska_2])             
                                                                                                                
  current_section                                                                                               
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If complexity is getting to high for a method it's usually a good idea to split out helper methods. If you end up to pass in the same parameters to each of these methods, it could also be a good idea to extract a class.

Some solution could be

```rb
def check_for_next_section(line, current_section)
  ZoneCheck.new(line, current_section).run
end

class ZoneCheck
  SECTION_HEADERS = {
    hawaii_1: '"[2] For Hawaii, the following Postal Codes are Zone 44 for Ground',
    hawaii_2: '"For Hawaii, the following Postal Codes are Zone 46 for Ground',
    alaska_1: '"[3] For Alaska, the following Postal Codes are Zone 44 for Ground',
    alaska_2: '"For Alaska, the following Postal Codes are Zone 46 for Ground'
  }.freeze

  def initialize(line, current_section)
    @line = line
    @current_section = current_section
  end

  def run
    if zones?
      :zones
    elsif hawaii_1?
      :hawaii_1
    elsif hawaii_2?
      :hawaii_2
    elsif alaska_1?
      :alaska_1
    elsif alaska_2?
      :alaska_2
    else
      current_section
    end   
  end

  private

  attr_reader :line, :current_section

  def zones?
    current_section == :preamble &&
      line.starts_with?('Dest. ZIP')
  end

  def hawaii_1?
    current_section == :zones &&
      !line.blank? &&
      line.starts_with?(SECTION_HEADERS[:hawaii_1])
  end

  def hawaii_2?
    current_section == :hawaii_1 &&
      line.starts_with?(SECTION_HEADERS[:hawaii_2])
  end

  def alaska_1?
    current_section == :hawaii_2 &&
      line.starts_with?(SECTION_HEADERS[:alaska_1])
  end

  def alaska_2?
    current_section == :alaska_1 &&
      line.starts_with?(SECTION_HEADERS[:alaska_2])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not understand why `!line.blank?` is needed. Assuming it is not you could create a second constant:

```
NEXT_SECTION = {
  { current: :preamble, line_start: 'Dest.' }                    => :zones 
  { current: :zones,    line_start: SECTION_HEADERS[:hawaii_1] } => :hawaii_1
  { current: :hawaii_1, line_start: SECTION_HEADERS[:hawaii_2] } => :hawaii_2,
  { current: :hawaii_2, line_start: SECTION_HEADERS[:alaska_1] } => :alaska_1,
  { current: :alaska_1, line_start: SECTION_HEADERS[:alaska_2] } => :alaska_2
}.freeze
```

and write your method as follows.

```
def next_section(current_section, line)
  h, next_section = NEXT_SECTION.find do |h, next_section|
    h == { current: current_section, line_start: line[0, h[:line_start].size] }
  end
  h.nil? ? current_section : next_section
end
```